# Problems with setting the Text of a Chip within a ChipGroup

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

Probably the Solution to my Problem is very simple, but obviously I am missing something and am stuck with fixing it myself.

**Problem:**

I want to have a ChipGroup were Users can filter content from a RecyclerView but unfortunately I am getting an error when trying to set the text.

```
/home/noah/StudioProjects/.../app/src/main/res/layout/filter_dialog.xml:104: error: attribute text (aka [...]:text) not found.
```

Code:

```
<android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_m">

            <android.support.design.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:text="Lab 1" />

            <android.support.design.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:text="Lab 2" />

...
```

**What I already tried:**

- switching between `app:text` and `app:chipText`
- adding `implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha02'` but this caused various problems with other implementations that I have in my gradle-file

**dependencies**

```
 {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'
    implementation 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you try android:text ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip):

> android:text - Sets the text of the chip.